# Help with Installing packages and repositories

Tags: usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install a few different packages but am at a loss on getting them to work.

For example, I am trying to install usb_cam and getting this error
mkdir: cannot create directory `build': Permission denied

Also, when there is a repository how do I add it? I keep trying to find it in the documentation but if someone wouldn't mind giving me an example.

mary_tts or usb_cam would be a good working example for me to go by if someone doesn't mind helping.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10431/help-with-installing-packages-and-repositories/) by [xalu](https://answers.ros.org/users/754/xalu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2011-06-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally you should not install packages by hand in system directories such as /opt/ros/diamondback. People normally create an overlay in their home directory. An easy way of creating such an overlay (and installing stacks/packages) is by using rosinstall. To create an overlay in ~/ros, you can do the following:

```
rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/diamondback
```

Then replace the line

```
source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash
```

in your `~/.bashrc` with the line

```
source ~/ros/setup.bash
```

Now, if you want to install a new stack that is not available as a debian package (e.g. bosch_drivers which contains usb_cam), execute the following:

```
roslocate info bosch_drivers > ~/bosh_drivers.rosinstall
rosinstall ~/ros ~/bosh_drivers.rosinstall
```

After opening a new terminal to reload setup.bash you will have the package usb_cam in your package path and you should be able to rosmake it.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xalu](https://answers.ros.org/users/754/xalu/) on 2011-06-29**:
Thanks Lorenz! :)    I had time to set this up and just used this, wow does that make everything work :). Why isn't this page one of the tutorial? Thanks again. Really makes everything much easier.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-06-29**:
You can find install instructions here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall

**Comment by [xalu](https://answers.ros.org/users/754/xalu/) on 2011-06-29**:
Thanks! Okay. I tried rosinstall and roslocate, but both are  command not found. I looked them up and they should be installed when I set up ROS?